# Can't connect to SQL Developer through remote computer

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, firewall, iptables

I am trying to connect to Oracle through SQL Developer in a remote computer.

The listener is up, as I verified using the command:

```
lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 12-JUL-2018 13:59:38

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                12-JUL-2018 13:40:56
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 18 min. 42 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/sicm/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "cfmisiro.cross.dc.uel.br" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "fmisiro", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "fmisiro.cross.dc.uel.br" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "fmisiro", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "fmisiroXDB.cross.dc.uel.br" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "fmisiro", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

I configured the iptable with the command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0 --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
```

The port is being listened:

```
netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1521          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:61544           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::23064                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22312                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

However when I try to connect from a remote computer, it fails.

Trying to connect through telnet:

```
telnet host 1521
```

I get the error:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

When I try to connect through SQL Developer, I get the error:

```
Status : Erro de ES: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

What am I missing?

I have another database that connects to the SQL Developer.

This one:

```
lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 12-JUL-2018 14:34:18

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                29-JUN-2018 14:30:41
Uptime                    13 days 0 hr. 3 min. 37 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "fmisir.cross.dc.uel.br" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "fmisir", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "fmisirXDB.cross.dc.uel.br" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "fmisir", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Your listener is only listening on localhost - not any external IP (whatever your `host` resolves to) that you could reach from a remote computer.But the timeout suggests there may also be a firewall in the way.

Comment: Ok.. it can be a problem... but, why telnet command is not connecting to the host too?

Comment: Because nothing is listening on port 1521 on whatever IP address `host` resolves to. But as I say, it's getting 'timed out' rather than 'refused' so there may be a firewall too.

Comment: [Possible duplicate for the IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51253149/266304), but there are many others; fix that first and see if you can connect (or is still blocked by a firewall).

Comment: I have another database in another server that is configured only to localhost that works fine to remote computer...

Comment: I will add this listener information (the one that is working)

Comment: You must have something else forwarding the connection then, like an SSH tunnel.

Comment: Indeed, you are right.